# Casting an object reference in c#

Tags: c#, object, casting, ref

If I have a function that takes a reference to an object.  How do I cast the parameter to avoid a type mismatch?

```
Dictionary<string, string> mySettings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
.
.
saveSettings(ref mySettings);
.
.
void saveSettings(ref object)
{
}
```

The call to saveSettings results in the following error message:

cannot convert from 'ref Dictionary' to 'ref object'

I'm not looking for a workaround, I've done that, I would like to know if this direct approach is possible.

Comment: why would `saveSettings()` take a ref to an object? What are you trying to achieve? I'm sure there's a better solution once you can clarify.

Comment: void saveSettings (ref object theObject) would be the correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var objectMySettings = mySettings as object;
if (objectMySettings != null)
    saveSettings(ref objectMySettings);
```

Comment: The generics solution is a good recommendation.  Since this addresses my specific question, I chose it as the preferred answer.

Comment: I must say that this way reference to mySettings object won't be passed to objectMySettings, so if you assing null to objectMySettings in saveSettings method, mySettings object will still have value, it won't be nulled and hence real ref behavior is lost

Answer (score 3):

If save settings is taking multiple types, why not use a generic instead? Esp if they share a common interface.

```
void saveSettings<T>(T obj);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. What if I pass 2 parameters, the first parameter is a filename (string) and only the second parameter needs to be specified as generic? What's the syntax for that?

Comment: void saveSettings<T>(string filename, T obj)

Answer (score 1):

```
void saveSettings(ref object)
```

The definition of saveSettings is malformed. You need an identifier after "ref object". But I'd make the "ref object" a Dictionary instead.

Comment: Redefining the parameter to a specific type would limit the function.  But that IS my current workaround.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a generic like another poster mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> mySettings = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    saveSettings(mySettings);
}

void saveSettings( Dictionary<string, string> Settings)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
static void Main()
{

   Dictionary<string, string> mySettings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   object o = mySettings;
   SaveSettings(ref o);
   // o now has an item.
}

static void SaveSettings(ref object o)
{
    var d = o as Dictionary<string, string>;
    d.Add("Some", "String");
}
```

**EDIT** Some debugging output.
[image]

Comment: See my comment to HelloWorld.  Your solution does not update mySettings, which is what I need it to do. But thanks.

Comment: Yes it does Mike. Applying it to my code didn't, I'll have to investigate that.  Thanks for your solution.